# What is wrong with my layout file? Text overlaps

Tags: android, android-layout

My texts in my layouts are overlapping or something and the text is cut off i'm not sure why, please help I'm making an app and i'm relatively new to XML so i need everything to look the same other then the text being cut off. I also put a screenshot of the layout so you can see what text is being cutoff.

Here is my XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            tools:context=".MainMenu"
            android:background="#ffcf688f">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/menuimage"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/toBattleButton"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/menuimage"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Store"
    android:id="@+id/store"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Battle"
    android:id="@+id/battle"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="60sp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toStoreButton"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toBattleButton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toStoreButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/battle"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/battle"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:singleLine="false"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/menuText1"
            android:editable="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ff9cf8ff"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/menuText2"
            android:textSize="20sp"

            android:textColor="#ff9cf8ff"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/menuText3"
            android:textSize="20sp"

            android:textColor="#ff9cf8ff"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/menuText4"
            android:textSize="20sp"

            android:textColor="#ff9cf8ff"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/menuText5"
            android:textSize="20sp"

            android:textColor="#ff9cf8ff"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[I cant figure out why the text is cut off at the bottom (in blue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEvkg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Trying using LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the elements one after the other use this attribute in relative layout

```
 android:layout_below = "@+id/aboveElementId"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is nested where it needn't be.

Have a good read through [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) to understand that it's unnecessary to have a LinearLayout for each TextView. You should realise that what you're trying to accomplish can be done with a single `LinearLayout`, two `Space`s and however-many `Textview`s. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/menuimage"
    ...>

<Space
    android:weight="1"
    .../>

<TextView
    .../>

<Space
    android:weight="1"
    .../>

<TextView
    .../>
<TextView
    .../>
<TextView
    .../>
<TextView
    .../>
<TextView
    .../>
</LinearLayout>
```